# Movetowards , Addforce , translate none is working why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

I just want to move a bullet (but it doesn't work) and test on cube (but the code too did not move the cube).

The commented codes also did not move the game object.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class movetest : MonoBehaviour 
{
    //public GameObject cube;

    // Use this for initialization
    public GameObject testmovecube;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    void Start () {
        //testmovecube = this.GetComponent<GameObject>();
        //rb = testmovecube.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        move();
       // 
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    private void move()
    {
        testmovecube.transform.position = 
    Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector3(226, 1, 226) , 2);
        //transform.Translate(Vector3.forward);
        //rb.AddForce(Vector3.forward);

    }
}
```

Please any help is appreciated.

Comment: `move()` is only called once in the `Start` function. You need to call it in the `Update` function every frame. Please read/watch basic Unity stuff before going forward. There are may tutorials out there. If you want to use `AddForce`, you need a multiplier to make it work since `Vector3.forward` is not strong enough to move it Use `rb.AddForce(Vector3.forward*150f);`. That should be strong enough to move it.

Comment: @Gleb Kemarsky ,,, Thanks for it very much.